# Past participle in German with "ge-"?

Tags: past-participle, past

Why does

> we have rented this villa.

translate to

> wir haben dieses Ferienhaus gemietet?

why user past participle if it the tense is still present?

Comment: "rented" is past tense, as well. It is a literal translation, where is the actual problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tense is not present, it's "Perfekt" -- what you'd call "present perfect" in English, but which expresses actions or states having occurred in the **past** in German.

The surface structures are actually the same in English and German:

> have rented
>
> haben gemietet